# Looking for a Django blog engine allowing to create several blogs in a Django app

Tags: django, blogs

I'm looking for a Django blog engine with typical features (tinymce editor, moderated comments, tags, pagination) allowing to create several distinct blogs in a Django app.
I've looked at https://github.com/timmygee/django-richtext-blog, but it seems to allow creating only one blog.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a finite, known number of blogs that will be made, or is this  a dynamic, publicly exposed feature, as in "user registers and gets a blog" type functionality?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: finite, known number of blogs

Comment: Have you checked out the CMS comaprison page at djangopackages? There are 9 apps claiming to be "multisite", and 3 of them are "multi-tenant". http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Daniel Eriksson, there is a list [here](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/).

Answer (score 0):

There is one that I am aware of on github that has multiple blogs as a feature, integrated into one database:

https://github.com/ilblackdragon/django-blogs

Though I personally haven't used it.

I don't know enough about your use case, but if you like richtext-blog, and since you have a finite known number of blogs, would it be feasible to set up multiple instances of richtext-blog on subdomains?  I suppose this would require that the data models need not be shared, which could conceivably be a deal-breaker, but it would probably be the fastest way to get the job done, if RAD is a consideration here.  You could setup a small wrapper on the root domains (.domain.com and www.domain.com) to link to the different available blogs.